# Pinescript - are custom methods inlined?

Tags: pine-script

I found some interesting behaviour when experimenting with `var` and custom methods:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")

x = 1
y = 1

function() =>
    var k = bar_index
    k

if close < open
    x := function()

y := function()

plot(x)
plot(y, color=color.green)
```

[image]

By setting `var k = bar_index` it's setting the value of `k` to the first bar index when its called. It's called first in `y := function()` which causes k to be set to `0`. However, when called again by `x := function()` the value of k appears to be 9 however x still has the value of 0 (as seen in plot) suggesting that functions are inlined. Is this true, as this is not mentioned in the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A distinct history is maintained for each call to the same function, so the effect is similar to that of an inline function. It is explained [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Functions_and_annotations.html#execution-of-pine-functions-and-historical-context-inside-function-blocks) in the usrman.

As to `var`, it initializes the variable only the first time it is executed. While in most cases this will be on the dataset's first bar, if the declaration statement is used in a local block whose execution is restricted, it will initialize the variable only upon the statement's first execution in that block, example:

```
if barstate.isrealtime
    var int a = bar_index
```

will only initialize the variable on the first execution of the script on a realtime bar, so `a` will be the `bar_index` of that bar.